# why the return type of return(str) is string&

Tags: c++, c++14, decltype

From https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/cpp14-language

```
string  lookup1();
decltype(auto) look_up_a_string_1() { auto str = lookup1(); return str; }
decltype(auto) look_up_a_string_2() { auto str = lookup1(); return(str); }
```

> The first returns `string`, the second returns `string &`, which is a
>   reference to the local variable `str`.

Why does `look_up_a_string_2` return `string&`?